# What on earth does 'a blowtorch in the mountains' mean? There's no other meaning for that in dictionaries except "a tool to produce flame"

Tags: word-meaning

My guess is that it refers to crown fires. Like, fires that are caught by upper levels of vegetation. Am I right?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: It really doesn't have any set meaning.  "Blowtorch" is often used metaphorically to refer to anything burning intensely, so it would be a reasonable expression to refer to any intense fire taking place in the mountains (not necessarily a crown fire).  But in other contexts it could mean different things.

Comment: The only search result for "a blowtorch in the mountains" is this question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/9drrEQ4XnQk?t=25